# Audio engine fails only on device(iphone6s) running iOS10 , runs on All simulator devices well or real device til iphone 6s

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, core-audio, ios10

I do try to add efect to audio file , it does work on iOS 9, but in iOS10 it fails only in iphone 6s ,runs on older devices , runs well in simulator,I do have privace usage description in my info.plist file for photo,camera and microfon
I do get the fallopian error on line audioEngine.mainMixerNode.installTapOnBus

```
2016-09-21 13:08:20.109701 $$$$[557:86076] [central] 54:   ERROR:    [0x16e34f000] >avae> AVAudioNode.mm:751: AUSetFormat: error -10865 
2016-09-21 13:08:20.110111 Tell Your Story[557:86076] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'error -10865'
```

my func for adding effect on audio

```
   private fund addEffetToAudioFile(pitch: Float, rate: Float, reverb: Float, echo: Float) { // Initialize variables
    audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    audioEngine.attachNode(audioPlayerNode)

    // Setting the pitch
    let pitchEffect = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()
    pitchEffect.pitch = pitch
    audioEngine.attachNode(pitchEffect)

    // Setting the platback-rate
    let playbackRateEffect = AVAudioUnitVarispeed()
    playbackRateEffect.rate = rate
    audioEngine.attachNode(playbackRateEffect)

    // Setting the reverb effect
    let reverbEffect = AVAudioUnitReverb()
    reverbEffect.loadFactoryPreset(AVAudioUnitReverbPreset.Cathedral)
    reverbEffect.wetDryMix = reverb
    audioEngine.attachNode(reverbEffect)

    // Setting the echo effect on a specific interval
    let echoEffect = AVAudioUnitDelay()
    echoEffect.delayTime = NSTimeInterval(echo)
    audioEngine.attachNode(echoEffect)

    // Chain all these up, ending with the output
    audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: playbackRateEffect, format: nil)
    audioEngine.connect(playbackRateEffect, to: pitchEffect, format: nil)
    audioEngine.connect(pitchEffect, to: reverbEffect, format: nil)
    audioEngine.connect(reverbEffect, to: echoEffect, format: nil)
    audioEngine.connect(echoEffect, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)

    // Good practice to stop before starting
    audioPlayerNode.stop()

    // Play the audio file
    if (audioEngine != nil) {
        audioEngine?.stop()
    }

    do {
        audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: self.recordedAudioURL)
    } catch {
        print("Error: Can't create audio file")
        self.showAlert(TYSAudioEditorHelper.Alerts.AudioFileError, message: String(error))
        return
    }

    audioPlayerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler: {
        print("Complete")
    })

    try! audioEngine.start()

    let dirPaths: AnyObject = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,  NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    let tmpFileUrl: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(dirPaths.stringByAppendingPathComponent(kOutputSoundWithEffectFileName))
    do {
        self.newAudio = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: tmpFileUrl, settings:[
            AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_HE),
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Medium.rawValue,
            AVEncoderBitRateKey : 12800,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
            AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0
            ])

     /*Error in this line*/   audioEngine.mainMixerNode.installTapOnBus(0, bufferSize: 2048, format: audioEngine.mainMixerNode.inputFormatForBus(1)) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void  in
            print(self.newAudio.length)
            if (self.newAudio.length) < (self.audioFile.length) {
                //Let us know when to stop saving the file, otherwise saving infinitely
                do {
                    try self.newAudio.writeFromBuffer(buffer)
                } catch {
                    print("Problem Writing Buffer")
                }
            } else {
                self.audioEngine.mainMixerNode.removeTapOnBus(0)
                //if we dont remove it, will keep on tapping infinitely
                self.newAudio = nil
                if (self.audioEngine != nil) {
                    self.audioEngine?.stop()
                }
                self.removeOldFileIfExist(self.kOriginalVideoSoundFileName)
                self.saveAudioFileInVideo(tmpFileUrl)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Problem")
    }

    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        showAlert(TYSAudioEditorHelper.Alerts.AudioEngineError, message: String(error))
        return
    }

    // play the recording!
    audioPlayerNode.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/1584138-anonymous/kaudiouniterr_propertynotwritable?language=objc that error is

> kAudioUnitErr_PropertyNotWritable = -10865

According to https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudionode/1387122-installtap

> format: 
>   If non-nil, attempts to apply this as the format of the specified output bus.
>   This should only be done when attaching to an output bus which is not connected to another node; an error will result otherwise. The tap and connection formats (if non-nil) on the specified bus should be identical. Otherwise, the latter operation will override any previously set format.
>   For AVAudioOutputNode, tap format must be specified as nil.

So could be one of the following:

1. mainMixerNode is already connected to another node, so you need to disconnect them before installing the tap
2. mainMixerNode is an AVAudioOutputNode, so you need to pass in nil for this argument

Comment: found the problem  just have to comment this line -> //try! audioEngine.start()

Comment: @ivan123 commenting audioengine.start function directly gives you error because its the case that audioengine should be started .Did you solve the issue ?